# Which of the following polynomials lies in the linear span of $S=\{1,1+x+x^2\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Which of the following polynomials lies in the linear span of $S=\{1,1+x+x^2\}$

1. $100x^2 + 10x+10$
2. $5x^2+5x+1$

Comment: Please check all of your spelling and use a more relevant title!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

$$5x^2+5x+1=5(x^2+x+1)-4(1)$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that a polynomial $p(x)$ is in the linear span of S if

$p(x)$ = $c_{1} \cdot 1 + c_{2} \cdot (1 + x + x^{2})$, where $c_{1}, c_{2}$ are constants

Can you immediately see why one of your polynomials is in the span of S and the other isn't?

Comment: One of the polynomials cannot be in the span of S because the coefficients of $x^{2}$ and $x$ are not the same.